# Change format of \namepartgiveni

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to change the format of the name initials in my own BibLaTeX style, but I can't get it to work.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{LAST-first}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\MakeUppercase{\namepartfamily}}%.. WORKS
    % {\namepartgiveni}%................ WORKS
    {\MakeLowercase{\namepartgiveni}}%.. DOESN'T WORK
    {\namepartprefix}%
    {\namepartsuffix}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{LAST-first}%

\begin{document}
  \cites{aksin}{baez/article}{bertram}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(I actually want to conditionally print the whole name in small caps, but I think just making `\namepartgiveni` lowercase illustrates the problem well enough.)

I also tried to change it in the `name:family-given` macro, but I get the same error (`! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.` and so on).

---

**Edit:**

My answer below doesn't really work for what I want, since it changes the style in the citations too, not just in the bibliography. Here's another MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=abnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \textcites{aksin}{baez/article}{bertram}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the name is capitalized in the text too, not just in the bibliography. So I'm back to square one. Any ideas?

Comment: `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}` will restrict the redefinition to the bibliography only

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I don't even know how I managed to figure this out, since it's not in the manual and I was just reading random lines of code from `biblatex.def`, but apparently we can change the format for each part by redefining `\mkbibnamefamily`, `\mkbibnamegiven` and so on.

So, for my original example, this does the deal:

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\ifgiveninits{\MakeLowercase{#1}}{#1}}
```

I'm not sure if this is the optimal way to do it, so if anybody has any objections please let me know. So far it seems to work fine though.

Edit: As per @moewe's comment above, the redefinition has to be inside `\AtBeginBibliography` so that it doesn't affect the citations too.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want? The `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}` looks good so far and is far better than to mess with the arguments to `name:family-given`. But maybe there is an even easier way to do what you want.

Comment: @moewe Well, usually I want the name to be printed as “LAST, First” but I added an option to use small caps, and if the user calls it along with `giveninits` I want the initial to be in small caps too. So what I’m doing now is pretty much what I mentioned, except I also check for the small caps option besides giveninits, and I also make the text small caps besides lowercase. For the last name I just check the small caps option and make it upper case or small caps accordingly. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @moewe It turns out `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}` doesn't work for my needs, since it changes the citations too. I updated my question with another MWE. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @moewe Argh, this was too good to be true. It also changes the formatting for `byauthor`, `byeditor` and other names like that. When I defined the `LAST-first` name format I could use it just for the main author/editor (label?). Any ideas?

Comment: stuff the redefinition into the format `\DeclareNameFormat{LAST-first}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\namepartfamily}%
    {\namepartgiveni}%
    {\namepartprefix}%
    {\namepartsuffix}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}`

Comment: @moewe Perfect, I can't thank you enough. :)