# Detect single initial with l3regex

Tags: biblatex, expl3, l3regex

---

Edit: Now my problem is detecting when the argument to `\mkbibnamegiven` is a single initial. I'm trying to do that with `l3regex` but I can't get it to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{doe2016, author = {J. Doe}, date = {2016}}
  @book{doe2017, author = {P. Doe}, date = {2017}}
  @book{doe2015a, author = {John Doe}, date = {2015}}
  @book{doe2015b, author = {James Doe}, date = {2015}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfInitial}{mmm}{%
  \regex_match:nnTF{\w\.}{#1}{{\bfseries #2}}{#3}% Doesn't work
  % \regex_match:nnTF{^\w.$}{#1}{{\bfseries #2}}{#3}% Also doesn't work
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeLowercase{\scshape#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{
  \ifnumequal{\value{uniquename}}{2}{%
    \IfInitial{#1}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape#1}}{#1}%
  }{%
    \MakeLowercase{\scshape#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\cite{doe2015a}\\
\cite{doe2015b}\\
\cite{doe2016}\\% This gives me J. Doe, but I want j. Doe
\cite{doe2017}

\end{document}
```

---

Original question:

This is an extension of the question I asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395935/102699).

Using BibLaTeX, I'm trying to get the first name in small caps when it's just the initial, but in the normal font when it's the full name. So here's my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{doe2016, author = {J. Doe}, date = {2016}}
  @book{doe2017, author = {P. Doe}, date = {2017}}
  @book{doe2015a, author = {John Doe}, date = {2015}}
  @book{doe2015b, author = {James Doe}, date = {2015}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeLowercase{\scshape#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{
  \ifnumequal{\value{uniquename}}{2}{#1}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\cite{doe2015a}\\% First name is normal, like I want it
\cite{doe2015b}\\% First name is normal, like I want it
\cite{doe2016}\\% First name is normal, but I want it in small caps
\cite{doe2017}% First name is in small caps, like I want it

\end{document}
```

Ignoring the small caps, that gives me:

> John doe 2015
>
> James doe 2015
>
> J. doe 2016
>
> p. doe 2017

What I want, however, is:

> John doe 2015
>
> James doe 2015
>
> j. doe 2016
>
> p. doe 2017

Since the years are different, `doe2016` doesn't require the full first name, so we get just the initial. But the value of `uniquename` is still 2, as if we needed the full name. So how can I change the format of the first name for just the cases when only the initial is printed?

Comment: `uniquename` (unlike `uniquelist`) does not take the year into account. You will always get the same `uniquename` result regardless of the year. The problem is that for `biblatex` 'J. Doe' and 'John Doe' and 'James Doe' are three different people.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I guessed that much, but is there something that takes the year into account for me to check against then? How does BibLaTeX know when it should print just the initial or the whole name? Apparently it takes the year into account then, but I couldn't figure out where or how.

Comment: AFAIK there is no `uniquename` setting that would take the year into account. And there is no straightforward way to get it to do that from within `biblatex` (you'd have to essentially re-implement the entire `uniquename` feature, but in `biblatex`). `biblatex` gets the `uniquename` info from Biber. The idea here is to disambiguate names (people), it's not about labels that consist of a name and a year. What makes you thin it takes the year into account?

Comment: I think you need something else. You need to detect if a given name is an initial or the full thing. Now there are two reasons why you have an initial only (1) the input was an initial, there is no full name given, (2) `biblatex` truncated a given name to an initial for `unqiuename` purposes. Case (2) is easy to detect using the `uniquename` counter. But case (1) is tricky - there is no built-in detection that says whether a name was only given in initials-only form

Comment: @moewe Ah, my mistake! I thought it considered the year because  the `doe2006` entry in my example is printed as "J. doe 2016" instead of "John doe 2016", but that's because I only gave it the initial, of course. I guess I'd have to check if mkbibnamegiven's argument is composed of a single alphabetic character then. I'll try to do that. Thank you for your help, as always. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because `#1` is `\namepartgiven`, which you need to expand in order to get its current value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
%\usepackage{l3regex} % not needed with a recent version

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{doe2016, author = {J. Doe}, date = {2016}}
  @book{doe2017, author = {P. Doe}, date = {2017}}
  @book{doe2015a, author = {John Doe}, date = {2015}}
  @book{doe2015b, author = {James Doe}, date = {2015}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfInitial}{mmm}
 {
  \regex_match:nVTF {\w\.} \namepartgiven {{\bfseries #2}} {#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeLowercase{\scshape#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{
  \ifnumequal{\value{uniquename}}{2}{%
    \IfInitial{#1}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape#1}}{#1}%
  }{%
    \MakeLowercase{\scshape#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\cite{doe2015a}\\
\cite{doe2015b}\\
\cite{doe2016}\\% This gives me J. Doe, but I want j. Doe
\cite{doe2017}

\end{document}
```

[image]